# get_page_children() not returning all child pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have in my Wordpress theme, a section where I am getting child pages to display their information. This is what I have right now:

```
<?php 
                $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

                $staff = get_page_children(8, $all_wp_pages);

                foreach($staff as $s){
                    $page = $s->ID;
                    $page_data = get_page($page);
                    $content = $page_data->post_content;
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content',$content);
                    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
                    echo '<div class="row-fluid"><span class="span4">'; 
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page ); 
                    echo '</span><span class="span8">'.$content.'</span></div>';
                } 
        ?>
```

I have five child pages that should be showing up, but only three are returning. I used print_r on $staff to see if the other pages were even in the array, but they aren't. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Does Wordpress allow multiple children?

Comment: Could that be your problem? It is only returning the pages where the current page is the first parent selected or something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `get_page_children()` or `new WP_Query()`. By default `WP_Query` returns only the last `x` number of pages created. It's the limit imposed on `WP_Query`.

`get_page_children()` simply takes the pages array returned by `WP_Query` and filters the children pages from that list. According to WordPress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children): get_page_children "...does not make any SQL queries to get the children."

#### To fix the issue simply use:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1' );
```

#### Your code with the fix:

```
    <?php 
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1));

    $staff = get_page_children(8, $all_wp_pages);

    foreach($staff as $s){
        $page = $s->ID;
        $page_data = get_page($page);
        $content = $page_data->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content',$content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo '<div class="row-fluid"><span class="span4">'; 
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page ); 
        echo '</span><span class="span8">'.$content.'</span></div>';
    } 
    ?>
```

#### Here is a helper function that you can call whenever you need to get page children

```
    function my_get_page_children( $page_id, $post_type = 'page' ) {
        // Set up the objects needed
        $custom_wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $all_wp_pages    = $custom_wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

        // Filter through all pages and find specified page's children
        $page_children = get_page_children( $page_id, $all_wp_pages );

        return $page_children;
    }
```

#### Example

You code with with the helper function

```
    foreach(my_get_page_children(8) as $s){
        $page = $s->ID;
        $page_data = get_page($page);
        $content = $page_data->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content',$content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo '<div class="row-fluid"><span class="span4">'; 
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page ); 
        echo '</span><span class="span8">'.$content.'</span></div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem - looks like get_page_children behaves weird...  (in my case, for one page which had three children it returned three, for another with four it returned zero! - can't work it out..)

I got round it by using a custom query instead:

```
$params = array(
'post_type'=>'page',
'post_parent'=> 8,
);
$staff = query_posts($params);
```

Similar here:  http://www.sanraul.com/2010/08/28/get-page-children/

NOTE: depending on where you use this, you might need a `wp_reset_query();` as well - or else that `query_posts()` could break your main loop!

Hope that helps! - A

Answer (score 0):

```
$curID = get_the_ID();

query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'=>'page',
        'post_parent'=>$curID,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

echo '<ul>';
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';

wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

**SEE EDIT BELOW**

Having just experienced and solved this issue, I thought I'd share the approach I had to take.

Originally, I used a new WP_Query to grab all pages and then fed the query result to get_page_children():

```
$all_pages = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
$page_id = get_the_ID();

// pass $all_pages as the second parameter
$page_children = get_page_children( $page_id, $all_pages );

foreach ( $page_children as $childObj ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $childObj->guid . '">' . $childObj->post_title . '</a>'
}
```

For whatever reason, the above code did not work for me.

Instead, I passed the 'posts' object of $all_pages as the second parameter, like so:

```
$all_pages = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
$page_id = get_the_ID();

// pass the posts object of $all_pages as the second parameter
$page_children = get_page_children( $page_id, $all_pages->posts );

foreach ( $page_children as $childObj ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $childObj->guid . '">' . $childObj->post_title . '</a>';
}
```

I hope this helps someone!

---

**EDIT:**
After experiencing more trouble with the get_page_children() function, I choose a different route entirely that has been working consistently to achieve the same end result:

```
$page = get_queried_object();
$children = get_pages( 'child_of=' . $page->ID . '&parents=' . $page->ID );

// loop through the child page links
foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $child->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $child->ID ) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$args = array(
        'post_parent' => $parent_id ,
        'post_type'   => 'page', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
    $children = get_children( $args );
```

$children variable will give you to all children pages of parent ID. if you are using WP_Query make sure to reset query after code for more info 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_children/

use this code in your functions.php file and call function with parent page id

```
    function load_clildren( $parent_id=null ){
    $parent_id  =   ( $parent_id ) ? $parent_id : $post->ID;

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $parent_id ,
        'post_type'   => 'page', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
    $children = get_children( $args );
    return $children;
}
```

function call method

```
$ch_pages   =   load_clildren( $parent_id );
```

or 
using in parent page

```
$ch_pages   =   load_clildren();
```